# Track performance numbers

Tags: project-management, performance, continuous-integration, benchmarking

I have a (large) software project in a git repository. There is a benchmark suite that spits out lots of numbers (time per benchmark, allocations done per benchmark) I’d like to track.

What is the best way to get a grip on intended and unintended performance changes in such a setup?

(Ideally, I think, there is a piece of free software that takes a git repository, a script to obtain the numbers, schedules jobs for new commit, also checks old commits when idle and presents a slick web interface with lots of graphs and analysis tools.)

Comment: SonarQube has great graphs that measure software quality, unit test coverage and the number of unit tests passed.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, SonarQube looks close to what I’d like to have. Unfortunately, it doesn’t put its emphasis on benchmark metrics, it seems.

Comment: I also like [goperfd](http://goperfd.appspot.com/perfgraph?builder=linux-amd64&benchmark=json&procs=1&metric=allocs&metric=binary-size&metric=time&startcommit=3021&commitnum=100&refresh=Refresh) but it seems to be specific to go and not easily deployable for your own projects.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: I know about that rule, so I tried hard to formulate the question as a “how”, not a “what to use”.

Answer (score 2):

I have a limited amount of experience with [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). One thing I really liked about it was the dashboard display that had been set up by my colleagues, using plugins for Jira, Subversion, and Clover (code coverage). Jenkins supports quite a number of plugins and you can develop them yourself.

I know that [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) has a similar extensibility.

Comment: From a first glance, Jenking seems to be too much and also too little for this. If I need to develop plugins myself, I can proably hack something together from scratch.

Comment: Also, it seems that Jenkins doesn’t provide the “per commit” view that I want, but rather happens to be able to schedule jobs from new commits.

Comment: There are several ways you can configure Jenkins to run. Normally, I believe, it is set to poll, but it can also be triggered by external events, and it can be set to run on each commit. That requires a trigger provided by the version control system.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the best approach for your case is using Jenkins with the [Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin). It has nice graphs and can be used both with [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) and [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/).

Also test performance is important. [According to Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html#PracticesOfContinuousIntegration) it is better to run fast unit tests for every commit and slow integration and performance tests every few hours.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best way to get a grip on intended and unintended performance changes in such a setup?

I don't know anything about your benchmark suite, but as far as I understand the question, this can be implemented as an automatic test (I assume you have already a test suite with integration or acceptance tests in place). What you need is

- a possibility to record the performance values in a machine readable form
- a possibility to store the recorded values as reference values
- a possibility to compare recorded values from "the latest run" with the reference values, and if those values differ "too much", you this up as a "failed test".

Maybe you have to implement these three things by using some scripts on your own, but when your test suite allows unattened execution, it should not be too hard.

So whenever your regular (integration) test suite is run (for example, as part of a "nightly build"), you run also the performance test suite, and will be informed about unwanted changes in the same manner as you will be informed about any other failed test.

Have in mind that you have to define what "too much" means. Have also in mind, that the outcome of the performance results can be extremely hardware depedent, so when you have to run the test suite on different machines, or if the build server is working on too many other things in parallel during the tests, expect the results to be different.

So before throwing some arbitrary tools at the data to produce some nicely coloured charts you have to check manually after each run, check if that is really appropriate for your case, and if a fully automatic without any graphics does not suite your needs better.

Of course, charts may be helpful for analysing the root cause whenever the performance drops, but just for detecting a deviation I would avoid anything which needs manual interception.

EDIT: Rereading your question again, I am wondering if you are using an automatic build server, or if you currently do all builds locally. If you have no build server, that may be indeed the first thing to start with (independent from your performance tests). Afterwards you can integrate some automatic tests on that platform, and afterwards the performance tests. If you don't want to setup such a system, the minimum thing you need is a single script which will check out the complete source code to a clean directory and compile everything in one step. Afterwards you can try to integrate the automatic run of the performance tests. But I guess a server system is more appropriate, because otherwise you are going to block your workstation for a certain amount of time with each test run.

Comment: The most important numbers are, well, the performance numbers from benchmarks. The others that you list are just pretty nice-to-haves. Sorry if that wasn’t clear in the question.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: well, this were just the examples *you* gave in your original posting. Now you have stripped all the examples - which makes your question not really clearer. A description like "lots of numbers" leaves a lot room for guessing around.

Comment: Sorry, I thought “benchmark suite” is clear enough. I tried to amend it, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: see my edits.

Comment: Thanks. I guess “Maybe you have to implement these three things by using some scripts on your own” is the main take away here...

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: see my 2nd edit

Answer (score 0):

Some inspiration of what is possible can be found on these existing Performance Dashboards. Unfortunately, not all of them are free software, and neither of them seems to be ready-to-use by others:

- https://datazilla.mozilla.org/
- http://goperfd.appspot.com/perf
- [http://speed.pypy.org/](http://speed.pypy.org/timeline/#/?exe=3,6,1,5&base=2+472&ben=fannkuch&env=1&revs=200&equid=off)
- https://chromeperf.appspot.com/